# ChartJS pie chart, "filling" each segment to indicate another dimension

Tags: chart.js

I want to make a pie chart in ChartJS, where each segment is "filled" (with a different color) according to a certain percentage. Say the pie chart displays various categories and their relative sizes (dimension 1), then I want the partial fill of each segment to show, say, the percentage popularity of each category (dimension 2).

See the example below. I've tried to sketch up what I want. Here is a pie chart with 6 "categories" (segments), and where each are "filled" with a percentage. Note that I can not use a normal nested pie chart, as that would only allow a single, *same* percentage for each segment.
[image: example sketch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the chart.js [polar area chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart).

Comment: Nice, of course :) Maybe it's also possible to have *nested* polar charts, so I can supoerpose the two charts? Or maybe I really need a polar chart over a pie chart. Anyway, I think a simpler presentation (fewer dimensions at once) is the best approach. Thanks

Comment: @joakimk It is possible actually. I was able to extend the pie chart so that it also has a linear radial scale (like the polar area chart). The end result is a chart that's exactly like you had wanted. I call it a Polar Pie chart.  Im going to get it into npm next week and then you can use it like any other charts.js chart.